# using find and grep to empty multiple files

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

```
find . -name '.htaccess' -print | xargs grep -il 'sound' | xargs -p sh -c ">{}"
```

Trying to find some .htaccess files on a host that've been compromised, grep them to make sure they are bad .htaccess (not all on server have been ruined) and blank them out.

All is working, except the last part. Tried many variations of `echo >` etc.

I'm missing a fundamental here and can't seem to grok it out of all the man pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name '.htaccess' -print | xargs grep -il 'sound' | xargs -I {} sh -c ">{}"
```

Per usual, I get it minutes after posting a question.

Think it helps sometimes to just spell it out (literally)...

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the `: > filename` noop.

But would it not make more sense to remove the bad .htaccess files rather than zero them?

Comment: Maybe... they're there as a result of other apps (joomla, etc; hence the hacked htaccess). Interestingly, the original htaccess files seem to be intact in the directory in other forms (e.g. htaccess.txt). Right now, just want them 0'd. Also, I took out the php exec($_GET) backdoor that they were using, so for now...